# Filtering function in formula field

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am new to Crystal Reports (2016) and I´m working on an evaluation for our department now.
From CR I access data in a SAP Info set table. This works fine so far.

My data has the following the format and is read line by line:

[Source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suuAg.jpg)

As you can see, that sometimes there is a Q-Number with Position 100 AND 105, sometimes just with Position 100. So sometimes there are duplicates of the Q-numbers.
What I need is, that in case of an exisiting position 105 to just use this line. If there is no position 105, use the line with position 100. This should eleminate the duplicates and only leave the information I need.

After putting the new formula field in my report, it should show the data like this (column on the right):

[Needed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suuAg.jpg)

I tried that already with the "onlastrecord"-function, but without the needed result. It works to just use the line with position 105 in case of both positions. But Q-numbers with position 100 only are not displayed.

This is my code so far:

> If onlastrecord=true and (tonumber({Z_QM_INFOSET_CR.VIQMFE-POSNR})=0100)
>
> then {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR.QMEL-QMNUM} else
>
> if  (tonumber({Z_QM_INFOSET_CR.VIQMFE-POSNR})=0105)
>
> then {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR.QMEL-QMNUM}

I hope my case is understandable..

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you need a formula that prints the value in these situations:

1. show the q-number when position is 105
2. show the q-number when position is 100 and there is no 105 for the same q-number

So, i suggest an approach to check the next record and a contour condition for the last one.

Try this formula:

```
if {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR.VIQMFE-POSNR} = "0105" 
then {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR.QMEL-QMNUM}
else if onlastrecord and {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR.VIQMFE-POSNR} = "0100"
then {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR.QMEL-QMNUM}
else if {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR.VIQMFE-POSNR} = "0100"
and next({Z_QM_INFOSET_CR.QMEL-QMNUM}) <> {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR.QMEL-QMNUM}
then {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR.QMEL-QMNUM}
else ""
```

Comment: Thanks a lot heringer! That worked out pretty well!

Comment: But that just brings me to my next problem..

I want to use this formula field in a circle diagram. But if I pick "Amount of FORMULA field" for the box "Display values" he just counts all cases of the formula field - not just the ones with the Q-number..

If i change the group summary operation to "Amount of unique values" it shows me an illogical number.

Do you have an idea for that as well?

Comment: Have you tried a running total field? You can use it to count only when formula <> "".

Comment: Is there not the possibility to set in the diagram options anything like "only count if there is an "X" for this database field? I dont know the running total field..

Comment: If you look at the fields explorer, scroll it to the bottom, you will see the running total fields option there. Right click and create a new one. It is pretty intuitive. Give it a try.

Comment: Im sorry, but I do not understand this field. 
Take a look at these two pictures:
1. https://ibb.co/vqTdmwk 
2. https://ibb.co/rpn6VBX

The result makes absolutely no sense to me. I get out a 10.. I dont understand that..

Comment: I don't understand that language in the pictures (german?). But i see you didn't set the "Evaluate / Use a formula" ("Auswerten / Fomel verwenden"). I understand you should mark that option and use the folowing formula: {@nur Pos100} <> "". Furthermore, you should you type of summary "count" instead of "count distinct". In which section did you place the running total field?

Comment: With your formula the counting works. But in combination with another field for a circuit diagram the numbers make no sense. Please take a look at the following picutres to understand my problem:
1. https://ibb.co/FhDxKzD
2. https://ibb.co/WzdXMQf
I really don´t understand why it has to be this complicated.. :(

Comment: HA! I just got it. I created a group for the category and used the running total field as group counter with the option to reset its count by changing the catergory type (group). This works fine so far. 

Thanks a lot for your help!